# ARM64 Backtrace from link register

Tags: arm, backtrace

I am currently trying to get backtrace based on stack pointer and link register on ARM64 device using C program.

Below is example of objdump
bar() calls foo() with **240444:    ebfffd68    bl  23f9ec <foo@@Base>**

I can get link register (lr) and from that getting 23f9ec, save it to backtrace list as last routine.

**My question:** From below assembly code with current lr **0023f9ec <foo@@Base>:**, how to calculate to get previous routine with lr is **0023fe14 <bar@@Base>** using C language?

here is my implementation, but getting wrong previous lr

```
int bt(void** backtrace, int max_size) {
    unsigned long* sp = __get_SP();
    unsigned long* ra = __get_LR();
    int* funcbase = (int*)(int)&bt;
    int spofft = (short)((*funcbase));
    sp = (char*)sp-spofft;
    unsigned long* wra = (unsigned long*)ra;
    int spofft; 
    int depth = 0;
    while(ra) {
        wra = ra;
        while((*wra >> 16) != 0xe92d) {
            wra--;
        }
        if(wra == 0)
            return 0;
        
            spofft = (short)(*wra & 0xffff);
        
        if(depth < max_size)
            backtrace[depth] = ra;
        else 
            break;
     
        ra =(unsigned long *)((unsigned long)ra + spofft);
        sp =(unsigned long *)((unsigned long)sp + spofft);

        
        depth++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```
0023f9ec <foo@@Base>:
  23f9ec:   e92d42f3    push    {r0, r1, r4, r5, r6, r7, r9, lr}
  23f9f0:   e1a09001    mov r9, r1
  23f9f4:   e1a07000    mov r7, r0
  23f9f8:   ebfffff9    bl  23f9e4 <__get_SP@@Base>
  23f9fc:   e59f4060    ldr r4, [pc, #96]   ; 23fa64 <foo@@Base+0x78>
  23fa00:   e08f4004    add r4, pc, r4
  23fa04:   e1a05000    mov r5, r0
  23fa08:   ebfffff3    bl  23f9dc <__get_LR@@Base>
  23fa0c:   e59f3054    ldr r3, [pc, #84]   ; 23fa68 <foo@@Base+0x7c>
  23fa10:   e3002256    movw    r2, #598    ; 0x256
  23fa14:   e59f1050    ldr r1, [pc, #80]   ; 23fa6c <foo@@Base+0x80>
  23fa18:   e7943003    ldr r3, [r4, r3]
  23fa1c:   e08f1001    add r1, pc, r1
  23fa20:   e5934000    ldr r4, [r3]
  23fa24:   e1a03005    mov r3, r5
  23fa28:   e6bf4074    sxth    r4, r4
  23fa2c:   e58d4004    str r4, [sp, #4]
  23fa30:   e1a06000    mov r6, r0
  23fa34:   e58d0000    str r0, [sp]
  23fa38:   e59f0030    ldr r0, [pc, #48]   ; 23fa70 <foo@@Base+0x84>
  23fa3c:   e08f0000    add r0, pc, r0
  23fa40:   ebfd456d    bl  190ffc <printf@plt>
  23fa44:   e1a03009    mov r3, r9
  23fa48:   e1a02007    mov r2, r7
  23fa4c:   e1a01006    mov r1, r6
  23fa50:   e0640005    rsb r0, r4, r5
  23fa54:   ebffff70    bl  23f81c <get_prev_sp_ra2@@Base>
  23fa58:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
  23fa5c:   e28dd008    add sp, sp, #8
  23fa60:   e8bd82f0    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, r9, pc}
  23fa64:   003d5be0    eorseq  r5, sp, r0, ror #23
  23fa68:   000026c8    andeq   r2, r0, r8, asr #13
  23fa6c:   002b7ba6    eoreq   r7, fp, r6, lsr #23
  23fa70:   002b73e5    eoreq   r7, fp, r5, ror #7

0023fe14 <bar@@Base>:
  23fe14:   e92d4ef0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r9, sl, fp, lr}
  23fe18:   e24dde16    sub sp, sp, #352    ; 0x160
  23fe1c:   e59f76a8    ldr r7, [pc, #1704] ; 2404cc <bar@@Base+0x6b8>
  23fe20:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
  23fe24:   e59f66a4    ldr r6, [pc, #1700] ; 2404d0 <bar@@Base+0x6bc>
  23fe28:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
  23fe2c:   e59f26a0    ldr r2, [pc, #1696] ; 2404d4 <bar@@Base+0x6c0>
  23fe30:   e08f7007    add r7, pc, r7
  23fe34:   e08f6006    add r6, pc, r6
  23fe38:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
  23fe3c:   e08f2002    add r2, pc, r2
  23fe40:   e1a05001    mov r5, r1
  23fe44:   e3a01003    mov r1, #3
  23fe48:   e59f9688    ldr r9, [pc, #1672] ; 2404d8 <bar@@Base+0x6c4>
.....................................................................
  24043c:   e3a0100f    mov r1, #15
  240440:   e1a0000a    mov r0, sl
  240444:   ebfffd68    bl  23f9ec <foo@@Base>
  240448:   e59f2108    ldr r2, [pc, #264]  ; 240558 <bar@@Base+0x744>
  24044c:   e3a01003    mov r1, #3
  240450:   e08f2002    add r2, pc, r2
  240454:   e1a05000    mov r5, r0
  240458:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
  24045c:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already know about `lr`, so what are you missing?

Comment: I updated the question. Let say my lr is 23f9ec and save it  to back trace list as last routine, now from above assembly code, how to calculate to get previous routine with lr is 23fe14 using C language.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this.

Normally the register ABI of any operating system contains a "frame pointer" register. For example, on Apple's armv7 ABI, this is `r7`:

```
0x10006fc0      b0b5           push {r4, r5, r7, lr}
0x10006fc2      02af           add r7, sp, 8
0x10006fc4      0448           ldr r0, [0x10006fd8]
0x10006fc6      d0e90c45       ldrd r4, r5, [r0, 0x30]
0x10006fca      0020           movs r0, 0
0x10006fcc      fff7a6ff       bl 0x10006f1c
0x10006fd0      0019           adds r0, r0, r4
0x10006fd2      6941           adcs r1, r5
0x10006fd4      b0bd           pop {r4, r5, r7, pc}
```

If you dereference `r7` there, you get to a pair of pointers, the second of which is `lr`, and the first of which is the `r7` of the calling function, allowing you to repeat this process until you reach the bottom of the stack.

Judging by the assembly you posted, the codebase you're looking at doesn't have that. This means that the only way to obtain the return address is the same way that the code itself does: step forward through each instruction and parse/interpret them until you reach something that loads into `pc`. This is of course imperfect, since there may be functions in your call stack that do not ever return, but there's not much you can do about that.

It may be tempting to search backwards instead, and while you can do a heuristic approach and probably reach quite reasonable results with it, that is even less reliable than searching forward, since you have absolutely no way of telling whether you arrived at address X by stepping forward from the previous instruction or by explicitly jumping there from somewhere else.

Comment: How about in case of fp is available, getting lr & previous fp from it as below guide:
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/teaching/2001-02/arm-project/02-sort/apcs.txt

The stack backtrace data structure has the format shown below:

    save code pointer       [fp]        <-fp points to here
    return link value       [fp, #-4]
    return sp value         [fp, #-8]
    return fp value         [fp, #-12]

Comment: @NgocHoangNguyen If you look at `bar@@Base`, then you can see that while it _stores_ `fp`, it doesn't _set up a new_ `fp`. So `fp` if not being used as a frame pointer. Nothing is.